# Regex matches string#substring

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex matches any string in the following format:

`string#substring` -> where substring = substring of the string and string is only letters from `a` to `d`

e.g.

`abcddd#cd`  ***accepted***

`abcddd#cccc`  ***not accepted***

Comment: I feel like `.*?\1.*?(?=#(.*))` should work but I can't quite get it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: many regex implementations don't support forward references (JavaScript usually doesn't). That's probably why this isn't working.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am using the PHP option at https://regex101.com/r/Ndndkv/1 :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should meet your requirements:

```
[a-d]*?([a-d]+)[a-d]*#\1
```

It matches `abcddd#cd` but doesn't match `abcddd#cccc`.

Depending on your choice of tool and how you use it, you may or may not have to anchor it with a `^` and `$` at the beginning and end respectively (turning it into `^[a-d]*?([a-d]+)[a-d]*#\1$`).

[Experiment here](https://regexr.com/4kt5p).

Comment: Needs an `$` anchor at the end

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: that really depends on how it's used. For example if using something like `String.matches()` in Java, then it doesn't need it.

Comment: True but OP did not specify. I think adding the anchor is the most cross-flavor solution. I really like your solution and I am studying it to figure out why it matches the correct number of end chars but removing `#\1` makes it match differently.

Comment: ^[a-d]*([a-d]+)[a-d]*#\1$ is the correct one, as [a-d]*([a-d]+)[a-d]*#\1 doesn't accept aa#aa

Comment: @Hatim: it turns out the first group needs to be lazy for some input values (i.e. `*?` instead of `*`. Anchoring the regex with `^$` might still be useful, but the updated answer should match `aa#aa` even without it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It stills seems to match `abcddd#cccc` even though it shouldn't: https://regex101.com/r/6ZYvUN/2/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: it does not. If finds `abcddd#c` in that string, it doesn't match the whole string.

Comment: Correct, it matched part of the string when it should have thrown out the whole string. This would result in an erroneous `true` to be returned because the regex succeeded.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: and that's exactly why it depends on how you use the regex! Don't call `find` when you want to use `match`, that has nothing to do with the specific regex.